# I need help Funtion sort a-z condition

Tags: python

Condition
Get input name 2 value
Get input first or last

if first print output name at meet before

if last print output name at meet after

example1:

input

name1 : Yudkon

name2 : Anon

choose : last

output

-- Yudkon --

example2:

input

name1 : Somnamna

name2 : Somset

choose : first

output

-- Somnamna --

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `name1 = input("Name 1 : ")
name2 = input("Name 2 : ")
choose = input("Select first or last : ")
if choose == "first":
    if name1 > name2:
        print(name1)
else:
    pass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you got the logic from my code below, if you have any questions, please ask them :D

```
name1 = input("Name 1 : ")
name2 = input("Name 2 : ")
choose = input("Select first or last : ")

if choose == "first":
    if name1 < name2: # check if name1 is in front of name2 (alphabetical)
        print(name1)
    else:
        print(name2)
else:
    if name1 > name2: # check if name1 is after name2 (alphabetical)
        print(name1)
    else:
        print(name2)
```